# How to get a single data from NodeJS and display in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I created a database that has the details of users and I want it to be displayed my VueJS by searching its first name.

Below is my code to request details of the users in a JSON. It's working so my next step would be display the data in my VueJS.

```
http://localhost:9000/api/user/:id
```

I got something like this on my VueJS

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      results: {}
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getUsers();
  },
  methods: {
    getUser() {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:9000/api/user/")
        .then(response => (this.results = response.data))
        .catch(error => alert(error));
    }
  },

  computed: {
    /* Search Bar */
    filteredPeople() {
      if (this.search) {
        return this.results.filter(result => {
          return result.First_Name.toLowerCase().startsWith(
            this.search.toLowerCase()
          );
        });
      } else {
        return this.results;
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

and to display it, I created something like this

```
<div v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">
  <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search by name" />
  {{result.First_Name}}
  {{result.Last_Name}}
</div>
```

Here's my nodejs query to request a specific user

```
//gets a specific user based on their ID
router.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM MEMB WHERE id = ?";
    myDB.query(sql, req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Your query has error."+ err);
        } else {
            console.log(rows);
            res.send(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `getUser()` like that:

```
getUser() {
  let self = this;
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:9000/api/user/", {
      params: {
        id: 12345
      }
    })
    .then(response => (self.results = response.data))
    .catch(error => alert(error));
}
```

Comment: @Vin, what `console.log(response.data)` returns ?

Comment: None, idk why. Maybe I need to pass a data  .get("http://localhost:9000/api/user/" + id)? Something like that

Comment: @Vin, try to add the `id` like I did just now.

Answer (score 0):

Just a work around to this:

Please check this out: 
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#complete-example

It has got ready functions for bootstrap-vue to search by Name. All you have to do is:

1. Put a boostrap-vue table
2. Return an array of users from API to axios response
3. Set items to array of users

Comment: Can this table handle big data?

Comment: Yes. I tested it on 10000 records from mongo db.